# Incorrectly aligned field with strings

Tags: c#, struct, 64-bit

I have the following struct:

```
 public struct TEST_INFO
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public string FieldOne;
            [FieldOffset(16)]
            public string FieldTwo;
            [FieldOffset(20)]
            public string FieldThree;
            [FieldOffset(28)]
            public string FieldFour;
            [FieldOffset(32)]
            public string FieldFive;
        }
```

It compiles and run fine in x86 mode. When i compile and run it in AnyCPU mode (64bit), I get an exception during runtime "Could not load type TEST_INFO from assembly ... because it contains an object field at offset 20 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped"

Comment: `string` is a reference type, the structure needs to hold a pointer.  When you changed architecture, you changed the size of a pointer...

Comment: Now what is your question?

Comment: I am using a c++ library in my c# application. The original library struct is defined as follow:  typedef struct {
    CHAR    FieldOne[16];
    CHAR    FieldTwo[4];
    CHAR    FieldThree[8];
    CHAR    FieldFour[4];
    CHAR    FieldFive[8];
} TEST_INFO, *PTEST_INFO
  I am trying to convert the structure to C#  and ran into that exception issue during runtime in x64

Comment: You need to use fixed-length strings then, what you have now are pointers.